# How to send date values to ajax request to webapp handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, webapp2

I am trying to achieve plot a graph between two dates using google charts. basically i want to send date values to the controller which is written by using webapp2. i don't know how to send date values to controller using ajax.

1. how to retrieve date(input) values in the ajax block.
2. how to send date values to controller.

This is the JS function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
        url: "/tutorial",
        contentType: "application/json",
        context: document.body,
        success: function(response){
        var data1 = JSON.parse(response);
        //alert(data1);
        createChart(data1)
    }});
```

Comment: plz format your code.

Answer (score 0):

The date in javascript is Date Object type,so treat it like an object.
use:-
var date = new Date();
then either pass this variable date as it is in your data in ajax request or change it to string.Either way it will be passed to our ajax page